# Problem Iterating through a multi-dimensional array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach

Working on a Laravel application whereby I am consuming some data from an API. I get the response as a JSON object and convert to array. It appears as a complex multi-dimensional array 
(nested arrays). Am trying to loop through it using a nested foreach so as to reach out to the id of each item but I keep failing..

**The response is stored in a variable called usmDet**

The array response

```
array:1 [▼
  0 => array:1 [▼
    0 => array:3 [▼
      "id" => "74696"
      "agents" => array:13 [▶]
      "policies" => array:481 [▶]
    ]
    1 => array:3 [▼
      "id" => "1525"
      "agents" => array:8 [▶]
      "policies" => array:357 [▶]
    ]
  ]
  1 => array:1 [▼
    0 => array:3 [▼
      "id" => "73401"
      "agents" => array:1 [ …1]
      "policies" => array:8 [ …8]
    ]
    1 => array:3 [▼
      "id" => "210"
      "agents" => array:13 [ …13]
      "policies" => array:773 [ …773]
    ]
  ]
]
```

My nested foreach

```
 foreach($usmDet as $key => $value){
  if(is_array($value)){
    foreach($value as $key => $value){
      echo $key." ".$value."<br>";
    }
  }
  echo "<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The id is part of the array, as you can access it like `$value['id']`

In the second foreach to prevent confusion you should select a different name for the key and the value.

Try it like this:

```
foreach($usmDet as $key => $value){
    if(is_array($value)){
        foreach($value as $k => $v){
            echo $v['id'] . "<br>";
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

```
74696
1525
73401
210
```

[Php demo](https://3v4l.org/C7Nc2)

To get all the values for key "id" when multiple nested arrays, you could use [array_walk_recursive](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php)

```
$ids = [];
array_walk_recursive($usmDet, function($value, $key) use (&$ids){
    if ($key === "id") {
        $ids[] = $value;
    }
});

print_r($ids);
```

[Php demo](https://3v4l.org/lXgAq4)

Comment: It works fine,, thanks alot,, I have checked my code and noticed that the array has gone a depth further (agents is also nested array)  which contains some id property in it.. How can I access it ?

Comment: @Martin Do you mean like this? https://3v4l.org/tc79q You could use [array_walk_recursive](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php)

Comment: I have stored the values in a variable and dd on the browser https://3v4l.org/3NpBD and I get boolean true.. My objective is to store them in an array so that I can use them in the view in a foreach loop..

Comment: That is because array_walk_recursive returns a boolean.

Comment: Am not really sure if it will achiewve my objective cause I wanted to fetch them, store in a variable and return to the frontend/view whereby I ierate through a foreach loop and display each individually..

Comment: @Martin You could pass a variable by reference and add the ids to an array https://3v4l.org/lXgAq4

Comment: ,, It works fine thanks alot,, Just one last question,, can I use array_walk_recursive in more deeper array, for instance when agents has another nested array in it,, Cause the response am using has gone too deep which is so confusing to me

Comment: @Martin It walks through all the arrays in a recursive way. In this example you can see that all the keys with `id` from the nested arrays  are found https://3v4l.org/eWJfm

Comment: Okay,, Thanks alot sir,, You really helped me.. Had never worked with multi-dimensional arrays before